# How to Send/Read Image From HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, json, xmlhttprequest, httpresponse

I am trying to send a model containing an image using HttpResponseMessage response PostAsync.

To create the call, the code looks like this:

```
    //convert the file for upload
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream);
            var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(streamReader.BaseStream);
            imageArray = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
            imageModel.uploadImage.image = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);

            var jsonParams = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(imageModel.uploadImage);
            var content = new StringContent(jsonParams, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            //submit the file 
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
            {
                Uri baseURI = new Uri(_ServiceLocationRoot);
                client.BaseAddress = baseURI;
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(getUploadImageAddress, content).Result;
```

I have verified that the json created does contain the data I want to send, however on the receiving end, when I try to read back the json from the request using:

```
var requestContent = Request.Content;
string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

I am getting a null. Little help?
Thanks.

Comment: OK thanks for pointing that out. I am now closer (I think) but now I am getting a 415 'Unsupported Media Type' error every time I try to post. Any idea how I stop that?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks.